# SQL Server vs .Net Client - Best practice of returning Huge Data from server - Performance Improvement

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, performance

I am attacking performance issues in an Enterprise application. One of my SQL Proc returning More than 2 MB of data (XML plain text).  For executing that SP Its taking around 600 ms only with in the DB server. But, Its taking around 30 seconds to get response in my UI.

**SQL server 2008 / .NET 4.0  (IIS hosted windows application)**

Note :  In previous performance iterations - Too many DB calls clubbed together and hence avioded many DB calls. But now returning data is huge and facing this issue.

Please help on to identify any standard or restrictions best practices available here to improve performance.

Based on the comments received below thought of add this here:-

1. But I have found this while I am executing the same Sp call from my local SQLserver Query analyser with connectivity of onsite server. 2. Its not a intranet, but communication between US/India through Internet. 3. I analysed thouroughly using dottrace tool and source too. 4. There is no bottle neck of binding this data. Previousely around 15 Db calls were there with in Loop (every call carries small # of Kbs), but now reduced in to clubbed single call but carries large Data in MB.

Regards,
Karthikeyan.G

Comment: If it takes 600ms locally, it suggests this is a bandwidth issue; but 2MB, while non-trivial, is far from "huge" - what is the connection between the server and client here?

Comment: 2mb is also seriously trivial these days - not saying it should not be avoided, but 30 seconds for 20m over LAN, Wireless or DSL is not realistic either.

Comment: PLease check WHERE THE TIME IS SPENT. I seriously think you look at the wrong item. CHeck without UI binding, then check how much time the UI binding takes. I think you simple use that time in the UI.

Comment: 66k/s is a little slow if we're talking about an intranet. If your application access sql server indirectly, like through a web service/socket service, compress/decompress in both peer could be helpful. Otherwise, try to add a paging parameter to interface to slice data into pieces and use multiple calls to retrive the whole data, for your consideration.

Comment: Hey thank you guys-                                                 1. But I have found this while I am executing the same Sp call from my local SQLserver Query analyser with connectivity of onsite server.   2. Its not a intranet, but communication between US/India through Internet.   3. I analysed thouroughly using dottrace tool and source too.  4. There is no bottle neck of binding this data. Previousely around 15 Db calls were there with in Loop (every call carries small # of Kbs), but now reduced in to clubbed single call but carries large Data in MB.

Comment: @karthik but as noted by TomTom, make sure you know **exactly** what your timing includes; is it the data-binding or the data-transfer

Answer (score 0):

Certainly looks like the UI binding. 2Mb over the internet is unlikely to take 30 seconds but it could depending on your connection speed.

Considering it only takes 600ms to perform the SP it is a little long so it would be preferable to cache it. 2MB isn't much to cache anyway (as long as its not per user).

Get the 2MB of data, cache it, split it. Such as get the first 100 records, then bind those rows to your UI control and implement paging.

However without the code, I can't see what type and the depth of the data you are binding to what type of control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asynchronous programming:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "server=.\SQLEXPRESS; database=master; Integrated Security=true; Asynchronous Processing=true"

  Private Sub btnDisplayCustomersCallback_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayCustomersCallBack.Click
        Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
        Dim asyncResult As IAsyncResult
        'Example of Asynchronous Callback Model

        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [customer]"
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlConnection.Open()
        btnDisplayCustomersCallBack.Enabled = False


        Dim callback As AsyncCallback = New AsyncCallback(AddressOf DisplayCustomers)
        asyncResult = sqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader(callback, sqlCommand, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    End Sub

  Private Sub DisplayCustomers(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim del As DelFillGrid
        Try
            command = CType(result.AsyncState, SqlCommand)
            dr = command.EndExecuteReader(result)
            del = New DelFillGrid(AddressOf FillGrid)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            Me.Invoke(del, dr)

        Finally
            If (Not dr.IsClosed) Then
                dr.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub FillGrid(ByVal dr As SqlDataReader)
        Try
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            dt.Load(dr)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Because you're guaranteed this procedure 
            ' is running from within the form's thread, 
            ' it can directly interact with members of the form. 
        Finally
            btnDisplayCustomersCallBack.Enabled = True

            If dr IsNot Nothing Then
                dr.Close()
            End If

        End Try
    End Sub
```

In this, application will generate a ExecuteReader request in asynchrnous method and when the result is got the grid is filled. Till that time application do further processing.